# Como buscar por rango de fechas html con dos dataPicker

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

Como puedo buscar un rango de fechas en una tabla para mi columna (fecha creación) por medio de dos dataPicker que me permiten ingresar desde y hasta que fecha:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo html:

```
<form class="row g-3">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Fecha Creación Desde</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="creationDateFromCampaign"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Fecha Creación Hasta</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="creationDateToCampaign"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                            <br> <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
                            <br> <br>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <table class="table" id="tableCampaigns">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">[[#{table.listCampaigns.creationDate}]]</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="campaign:${listCampaigns}">
                                <td th:text="${campaign.creationdate}"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando la biblioteca de funciones de **datatable** o **datatables**? Si puedes, por favor, indica qué bibliotecas externas y versiones estás enlazando para poder reproducir tu problema. Todo, por ejemplo, bootstrap, jquery, datatable (o datatables) y cualquier otro complemento y el orden en el que cargas los CSS y los JavaScript. Gracias.

Comment: Estoy usando un componente de datatables, en mi caso componen de un template llamado dashforgehtml-10.

Comment: <script src="lib/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que deseas debes crearte una función de filtrado:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  (conf, fila, indice) => {
    /* Creamos las fechas máximo y mínimo desde el campo */
    const min = new Date(creationDateFromCampaign.value);
    const max = new Date(creationDateToCampaign.value);
    /* Aquí creamos la fecha de la fila en curso */
    const fecha = new Date(fila[0]);
    /* Comparamos la fecha con el rango */
    if (fecha >= min && fecha <= max) {
      /* Si está entre las fechas mostramos la fila */
      return true;
    }
    /* En caso contario no mostramos la fila */
    return false;
  }
);
```

Debes llamarla cada vez que modifiques el rango de fechas que deseas mostrar:

```
$('#creationDateFromCampaign, #creationDateToCampaign').on('change', () => {
    tabla.draw();
});
```

O cuando pulses el botón de búsqueda, tú decides.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo del código funcionando:

```js
/* Función de filtrado */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  (conf, fila, indice) => {
    /* Creamos las fechas máximo y mínimo desde el campo */
    const min = new Date(creationDateFromCampaign.value);
    const max = new Date(creationDateToCampaign.value);
    /* Aquí creamos la fecha de la fila en curso */
    const fecha = new Date(fila[0]);
    /* Comparamos la fecha con el rango */
    if (fecha >= min && fecha <= max) {
      /* Si está entre las fechas mostramos la fila */
      return true;
    }
    /* En caso contario no mostramos la fila */
    return false;
  }
);
 
$(document).ready(() => {
    const tabla = $('#tableCampaigns').DataTable();
 
    $('#creationDateFromCampaign, #creationDateToCampaign').on('change', () => {
        tabla.draw();
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-T584yQ/tdRR5QwOpfvDfVQUidzfgc2339Lc8uBDtcp/wYu80d7jwBgAxbyMh0a9YM9F8N3tdErpFI8iaGx6x5g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-BMbq2It2D3J17/C7aRklzOODG1IQ3+MHw3ifzBHMBwGO/0yUqYmsStgBjI0z5EYlaDEFnvYV7gNYdD3vFLRKsA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<form class="row g-3">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="form-label">Fecha Creación Desde</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="creationDateFromCampaign" value="2021-01-01" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="form-label">Fecha Creación Hasta</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="creationDateToCampaign" value="2021-02-01" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-12" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <br> <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
    <br> <br>
  </div>
</form>
<table class="table" id="tableCampaigns">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Desde</th>
      <th scope="col">Hasta</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-01-02</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-01-02</td>
      <td>Sí</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2022-01-02</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-UR25UO94eTnCVwjbXozyeVd6ZqpaAE9naiEUBK/A+QDbfSTQFhPGj5lOR6d8tsgbBk84Ggb5A3EkjsOgPRPcKA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" integrity="sha512-BkpSL20WETFylMrcirBahHfSnY++H2O1W+UnEEO4yNIl+jI2+zowyoGJpbtk6bx97fBXf++WJHSSK2MV4ghPcg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```